# Silverlight datagrid runtime adding and binding

Tags: silverlight, binding

I need to add columns to silverlight columns at runtime and also perform the bindings for the columns.

This is how i do it statically in xaml

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn  CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True"  Header="CriteriaName" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Path=[CriteriaName]}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
```

Now i want do the same in code behind,

here is what i have done

```
 foreach(string Col in lColumnNames)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn DGCol=new DataGridTextColumn();
                DGCol.Header= Col;


                Binding lObjBinding = new Binding(Col);
                lObjBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

                DGCol.Binding = lObjBinding;
                GrdQuickFindResult.Columns.Add(DGCol);


            }
```

This is not working.All i can see are blank rows in the DataGrid,as if the binding hasn't happened. Pls check and tell me if all the things that i have done using xaml is done using C# as well or is there some property that is left to be set in the Binding Object that i have created.
Thanx

Comment: Are you sure your "Col" collumn name matches the property name you want to bind to?

Comment: yes i m sure about that,,,,Header name and the property name are same,

Comment: Can u pls tell me how do i wtite the following piece of xaml code using c#  Binding="{Binding Path=[CriteriaName]}"
How can i set Path property .Merely 
Binding lObjBinding = new Binding(Col) is not helping
I tried removing the path keyword from xaml and all i see is empty rows as i see when i bind using code behind.
So i feel that its because i m not including this properly
**Binding="{Binding Path=[CriteriaName]}"** using c#. @Arthur

Answer (score 1):

A binding like:

```
"{Binding Path=MyProperty}"
```

is just a verbose way of writing:

```
"{Binding MyProperty}"
```

In the same way that

```
Binding b = new Binding();
```

is the same as

```
Binding b = new Binding("MyProperty");
```

And means that you are binding the text of your TextBoxColumn to the value of the property "MyProperty" in the data object which will be set as DataContext of a row in your DataGrid. For this we are assuming your data object is something like:

```
public class DataObject{
    public object MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

If your data objects are like that, your bindings in code behind are fine and they should work.

When you especify a binding like:

```
"{Binding Path=[MyProperty]}"
```

Or

```
"{Binding [MyProperty]}"
```

You are binding the the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) of the data object (if it implements one) and acessing the value corresponding to the the index "MyProperty". If you do this, I assume your data object is a IDictionary or a class which implements a indexer, like:

```
public class DataObject{
    public object this[object index]
    {
        get{ /*return something*/ }
        set { /*set something*/ }
    }
}
```

Just a suggestion: use [camel case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for your local variables, it looks strange for other people looking at your code, seems they are instance properties or static fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach(string Col in lColumnNames)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn DGCol=new DataGridTextColumn();
                DGCol.Header= Col;

                Binding lObjBinding = new Binding();
                lObjBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

                //=====This is what was missing======================//
                lObjBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("["+Col+"]");
                //==================================================//

                DGCol.Binding = lObjBinding;
                GrdQuickFindResult.Columns.Add(DGCol);


            }
```